# gerrit: access gerrit repositories as root user by using public key of another user

Tags: gerrit

We are using Active Directory for gerrit authentication and added our ssh-public keys to access git repos. If we use usernames same as AD users in linux boxes we are able to work well. But some of our work requires to use root user in linux boxes so we want to use root user completely to clone git repos and push changes to gerrit.

But when we try to clone git repos from root user we are getting below error message

```
git clone ssh://gerrit.doamin.com:29418/gitrepo.git
Cloning into 'girepo...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists
```

I have copied existing gerit user's ssh-key pair to /root/.ssh but still I am facing same issue.

Is it possible to access git repos in gerrit as root by copying public keys of another gerrit user?

Comment: Please give more details. What's the command that you're using to clone? Do you include the username of the user on the Gerrit server / in AD?

Comment: No StephenKing, I haven't included AD user in in URL. Edited my question with command I tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an [answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/repo-discuss/B_OkU2Esnw0) from gerrit google groups community. Thanks to "David Ostrovsky"

Adding an ssh alias in `/root/.ssh/config` and use it in clone command:

```
 Host gerrit
  HostName <gerrit server>
  User joe
  Port 29418
```

Comment: Sure, it's pretty obvious and that was what I was asking for. How should the Gerrit server know the user name. Without setting a `.ssh/config` up, you could just use this clone command: `git clone ssh://joe@gerrit.doamin.com:29418/gitrepo.git`.